# irregular list of lists to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Having a problem.
I need to convert an irregular list of list to a data.frame in wide format (i.e. I need same number of rows) and I just can't figure out how to do it.
List looks something like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 14

[[2]]
[1] 26

[[3]]
[1] 20 21 22 23

[[4]]
[1] 21 22

[[5]]
[1] 25

[[6]]
[1] 17 21 23
```

I've tried various approaches using for loops and/or sapply's but nothing works. The list elements being different lengths scuppers any attempt I've made. It occurs to me there must be a fairly straightforward way to do this. Mustn't there ? Can anyone advise ?

Comment: How do you want to fill the missing values?

Comment: NA's are fine, or "."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a `lapply` / `mapply` example...

```
#  Data
set.seed(1)
ll <- replicate( 4 , runif( sample(4,1) ) )
str(ll)
#List of 4
# $ : num [1:2] 0.372 0.573
# $ : num [1:4] 0.202 0.898 0.945 0.661
# $ : num [1:3] 0.0618 0.206 0.1766
# $ : num [1:3] 0.384 0.77 0.498

#  Find length of each list element
len <- sapply(ll,length)

#  Longest gives number of rows
n <- max( len )

#  Number of NAs to fill for column shorter than longest
len <- n - len

#  Output
mapply( function(x,y) c( x , rep( NA , y ) ) , ll , len )
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.3841037
#[2,] 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.7698414
#[3,]        NA 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.4976992
#[4,]        NA 0.6607978         NA        NA
```

Note, output is a matrix, so you need to wrap the output with `data.frame()`.

---

#### Row-wise filling and returning a data.frame

```
data.frame( t( mapply( function(x,y) c( x , rep( NA , y ) ) , ll , len ) ) )
#          X1        X2        X3        X4
#1 0.37212390 0.5728534        NA        NA
#2 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978
#3 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.1765568        NA
#4 0.38410372 0.7698414 0.4976992        NA
```

Comment: THanks Simon - that looks the business! But how can I make it so that the matrix fills rowise instead of columnwise ?

Comment: `data.frame( t( mapply( function(x,y) c( x , rep( NA , y ) ) , ll , len ) ) )`

Comment: Many thanks Simon. Works a treat....I have no idea how the magic in that statement works however!! Why the rep function in the middle ?!

Comment: Also, after you get `n`, you can do: `as.data.frame(lapply(ll, `[`, 1:n))`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
### set all lengths to maximum length (here=4)
### this will 'fill in' with NAs where needed
n <- 4
for (i in 1:length(ll)){
       length(ll[[i]]) <- n
}
matrix(unlist(ll), ncol=n)

### @Aruns approach is similar to the above;
### it uses the fact that subsetting by indices 
### which do not exist results in NAs e.g. 
> (ll[[1]][1:n])
[1] 0.3721239 0.5728534        NA        NA
### (using original `ll`)
d1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(ll, "[", 1:n))
colnames(d1) <- seq(4)
d1

### this is more roundabout
library(plyr)
### `ldply` takes list; returns data.frame
### default function applied is `rbind.fill`, which works here
### however `t` coerces this back to a matrix
### (using `ll` as modified by `for` loop in first answer)
t(ldply(ll))

       [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
1 0.3721239 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.3841037
2 0.5728534 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.7698414
3        NA 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.4976992
4        NA 0.6607978         NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward approach would be to get the data into a "long" form first (for example, using "melt"), adding a "times" variable, and then using `dcast` or `reshape` to get the data back into a new "wide" form.

These examples use `ll` from @Simon's answer:

Here's a "reshape2" approach:

```
library(reshape2)
ll2 <- melt(ll)
ll2$time <- ave(ll2$L1, ll2$L1, FUN = seq_along)
dcast(ll2, L1 ~ time, value.var="value")
#   L1          1         2         3         4
# 1  1 0.37212390 0.5728534        NA        NA
# 2  2 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978
# 3  3 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.1765568        NA
# 4  4 0.38410372 0.7698414 0.4976992        NA

## Or, for the other orientation:
dcast(ll2, time ~ L1, value.var="value")
```

You can also use the "data.table" package for this, if you are using at least version 1.8.11 of the package

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
packageVersion("data.table") ## Need at least V 1.8.11
# [1] ‘1.8.11’

DT <- data.table(ll)
DTL <- DT[, unlist(ll), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
DTL[, time := sequence(.N), by = nrow]
dcast.data.table(DTL, nrow ~ time, value.var="V1")
#    nrow          1         2         3         4
# 1:    1 0.37212390 0.5728534        NA        NA
# 2:    2 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978
# 3:    3 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.1765568        NA
# 4:    4 0.38410372 0.7698414 0.4976992        NA

## Or, for the other orientation
dcast.data.table(DTL, time ~ nrow, value.var="V1")
```

Both of these have the added advantages of conveniently replacing `NA` with anything else you wish to use.